# Signaling options change in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

In my first "real" iOS application, I want to push an options view and signal the main controller if any options are changed. The main controller creates an options object and passes it to the option view controller, which may change its properties; the question is how to alert the main controller of changes. I could come up with several ways to do this, but this seems like so common a thing that there must be a standard design pattern, and I haven't been able to find it. Recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling changes, actions, or user interaction in other views is the essential use case of [delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).  The best practice is to have the first view controller be the delegate of the options controller, and then as the user chooses one of the options, it calls certain methods on its delegate to notify it of the final choice.  In response to the delegate calls you could then reload the table view, disable/enable buttons, or any other updates you need to do.

Other options for keeping values/state in sync between views are:

- [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) - best used for data
- [Key-Value Observation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) - best used for data
- `NSNotification`s sent through [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - best used for actions